# Windows Command To List Expired User Accounts Only

Tags: windows, powershell, command

Using PowerShell, I would like to list user accounts that have expired only.

I've crafted the command below which lists all user accounts on my machine and also displays the account expires column:

```
get-localuser  | select Name, AccountExpires
```

Example output:

```
Name           AccountExpires
----           --------------
Administrator    
Guest           
test           09/05/2021 00:00:00
```

How do I only list expired accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I primarily work in a domain environment, but it looks like you can simply look at the AccountExpires property and compare it to the current date.  Something like below may work:

```
$Now = Get-Date
Get-LocalUser  | Where-Object{ $_.AccountExpires -le $Now }
```

You can `Select` whatever you like after that.

Comment: You are awesome! I modified the command to make it all in one line: get-localuser | Where-Object { $_.AccountExpires -le (Get-Date)} and it works perfectly.

Comment: NP.  The one-liner is fine.  I didn't go that route because there will be a slight change in Date Time per comparison.  Moreover, you'll be invoking `Get-Date` repeatedly.  Given these are local accounts, none of this is likely to be a big deal, but for larger sets, you may encounter performance issues and a widening gap between times that were used to compare.  At any rate, I'm glad it's working.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I will take this into account!

Comment: Good morning Steven! I had a quick question, is there a way to add an AND NOT equals to expression to that command? Sometimes the AccountExpires parameter is set to "Never" or is blank and I would like to exclude that from the command output.

Comment: Yes you can use the -and logical operator to add conditions to the `Where{}` clause. look at [about_comparison](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1) and the Logical Operators sections of [about_operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#logical-operators). I'd recommend using the -not*'s like `-ne`, `-notlike`, `-notmatch` etc. b4 resorting to logical operator `-not`. Note: Expressions can be arbitrarily complex.

Comment: Thank you, I used the -ne $null expression, however, it fails to work in my case, any chance you can help with the syntax please? get-localuser | Where-Object { $_.AccountExpires -le (Get-Date) -ne $null } | Select-Object -property Name, AccountExpires

Comment: Nevermind, got it to work with this expression: -and $null -ne $_.AccountExpires

Comment: Thank you once again!

Comment: Good job putting $null on the left side of the comparison. That's a best practice to avoid some gotchas in PoSh's type conversion system.